# How to unit test a component to check a particular component is rendered or not

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've a very simple custom component. I call it `NavbarComponent` and the selector is `app-navbar`. It is a very basic static navbar. I'm rendering it on `app.component.html`:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I'm writing a unit test case like this:
**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';

fdescribe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavbarComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    ...
  });

  it(`should have as title 'my-app'`, () => {
    ...
  });

  fit('should display navbar', () => {
    const fixture=TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled=fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('app-navbar')).toBeDefined();
  })
});
```

It's not working properly. The test is passed eve If i remove `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` from the template. I've just started with Unit testing few days ago. Please correct my mistake.

2 things I would like to mention:

1. I don't have any css (as of now).
2. No *ngIf condition so `NavbarComponent` should be rendered all the time.

Comment: First, you should not be doing this. [As stated here](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#nested-component-tests), for an App Component _Unit Test_ the sub-components are irrelevant. You should be testing each component in isolation - you should be stubbing out the subs. Second, all you are doing with this test is re-testing what the Angular team has already tested - it is a framework responsibility to provide/integrate components, so there is no need for you to test that. Only test your own code. Good luck to you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, Whatever you said makes more sense to me now. I was doing it wrong. I thank you for that. Actually It was just random thought at the back of my mind that what if I forgot to display the `app-navbar`. There should be someone to make sure it is there.  So this was my thought process. Please feel free to correct me :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have removed `app-navbar`

```
compiled.querySelector('app-navbar')
```

actually returns null, which is not undefined, that's why the toBeDefined check is passing.

Here you may want to use `toBeTruthy()` instead. Using this, your test case will pass if you have the `app-navbar` there and will fail if you remove it.

In JavaScript, there are six falsy values: false, 0, '', null, undefined, and NaN. Everything else is truthy.
[Read more here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobetruthy)

Comment: This solution worked. But I think I need more information. I'm going through the link you shared. Thanks